# Python - Leer lista dentro de matriz, que ha sido guardada en archivo texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Saludos.

Tengo una matriz 16 x 8 que a su vez, contiene listas en algunas de sus coordenadas. Se como enviar la matriz a un archivo texto, pero no logro tomar los datos del archivo y reescribirlos en una nueva matriz como enteros, respetando las listas internas.

Este es un ejemplo de la matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la matriz en el archivo de texto. Ahora quiero devolverla a una matriz en Python. He visto que algunos usan numpy, pero como estoy usando python 3.5.2, no me carga la libreria. Quisiera saber si me pueden dar otro metodo para lograr mi objetivo. De antemano, muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Hola César, por favor edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer assi, usando [json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json):

```
import json
matx = [1,2,3,4,5, [1,2,3, [1,2]]]
```

Para enviar la matriz a un archivo texto:

```
with open('tests.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(matx, f)
```

Para tomar los datos del archivo:

```
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
    matx = json.load(f)

print(matx) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2]]]
```